# event.pageX and event.pageY doesn't give me correct position

Tags: html, jquery

I user context menu using jquery on contextmenu event.
The html code of a menu is

```
<div id="contextMenu" class="dropdown clearfix">
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" style="display:block;position:static;margin-bottom:5px;">
  <li class="dropdown-item" tabindex="-1" data-id="duplicate-row">.../li>
  <li class="dropdown-item" tabindex="-1" data-id="show-in-modal">....</li>
</ul></div>
```

And the js code is

```
var $contextMenu = $("#contextMenu");
$(document).on("contextmenu", "div[id$='_container'] table tr td", function (e) {
  $contextMenu.css({
    display: "block",
    left: e.pageX,
    top: e.pageY
  });
  $element = $(this);
  return false;
});
```

The code above will give me miss in menu position.

The position will be fixed if I make the following:

```
 left: e.pageX-20,
 top: e.pageY -120
```

I used The same code above in many template nicely,  but now I am noting this problem.
Did any one know why this problem appear and  is my fixed worked at any other device?

Comment: If the code works in many templates but not in this case, something in the code arround it should cause the problem. Therefor you should add more of that code arround to your question.

Comment: What does this do? `$(document).on("contextmenu", "div[id$='_container'] table tr td", function (e) {`? Is "contextmenu" a custom event as described [here](https://api.jquery.com/on/)?

Comment: @RobMoll this code make right click event to any element that its id ends with "_container".

Comment: @biberman the only deference is the position of element that I want to make context menu for it.
It doesn't work if the element inside col-col-4  with scroll.

Comment: @RobMoll Yes it is...